# Hilchos brachos

Tags: tznius-modesty

We know it’s asur to make a bracha in front of a married women- who’s hair is exposed.

Does this apply to pictures of a married women with exposed hair?

If yes

Does this apply when a married couple hangs pictures of themselves engaged( when it’s perfectly fine to have exposed hair) but given now that they are married- would that make the picture an ervah?

Comment: I didn't know what you said in the 1st paragraph. (Be careful about a "we know" statement :-) Please source that. Re the last paragraph - if one should not be seeing a married woman with uncovered hair and you feel that it applies to pictures, then, a couple should never hang such pictures in a "public" room in their home - ever. It's not specific to saying a bracha.